# SQL: display newest entry

Tags: sql, grouping

I'm not really much of a developer, I only started self-learning VBA for Excel this year and I only started working with SQL two days ago...

That said: I'm trying to write a query that only shows the newest entry for each INVBTICKETNO based on ITTRANDATE but I can't seem to figure it out.

```
SELECT
  WHSNAME.WHSNNAME AS [Warehouse Name]
 ,VALID_BIN.BIN_TYPE AS T
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBBINNO AS [Bin Number]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBITEMNO AS [Item Number]
 ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.DESCR AS [Item Description]
 ,PRODUCT_CODE.DESCR AS [Product Code & Description]
 ,CUSTOMER.CSNAME AS [Customer Name]
 ,ORDERS.ORDER_NO AS [Oder No]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_OF_INVENTORY AS [Date of Inventory]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO AS [Ticket No]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBQTYONHAND AS [Qty on Hand]
 ,ORDERS.QTY_ORDERED AS [Qty Ordered]
 ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.SQUARE_FEET_UNIT AS MSF
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.EXTENDED_CST AS [Valuation?]
 ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITSOURCE AS Source
 ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITCOMMENT AS Comment
 ,MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) AS [Trans Date]
 ,ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG AS Flag
 ,SALESAGENT.SANAME AS [Sales Agent]
 ,ORDERS.CUST_PO_NO AS [Customer PO No]
FROM dbo.INVENTORY_BIN INVENTORY_BIN
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBITEMNO = INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.ITEM_NO
INNER JOIN dbo.WHSNAME WHSNAME
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBWHSNCODE = WHSNAME.WHSNCODE
INNER JOIN dbo.VALID_BIN VALID_BIN
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBBINNO = VALID_BIN.BIN_ID
    AND INVENTORY_BIN.INVBWHSNCODE = VALID_BIN.WHSNCODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_TRAN INVENTORY_TRAN
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO = INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO
    AND INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_LST_ACTIVITY < INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER CUSTOMER
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.CSCODE = CUSTOMER.CSCODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ORDERS ORDERS
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.ORDER_NO = ORDERS.ORDER_NO
INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCT_CODE PRODUCT_CODE
  ON INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.PROD_CD = PRODUCT_CODE.PROD_CD
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SALESAGENT SALESAGENT
  ON CUSTOMER.SACODE = SALESAGENT.SACODE
WHERE ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG = 'R'
GROUP BY INVENTORY_BIN.INVBITEMNO
        ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBBINNO
        ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBQTYONHAND
        ,INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_OF_INVENTORY
        ,INVENTORY_BIN.EXTENDED_CST
        ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.DESCR
        ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.SQUARE_FEET_UNIT
        ,WHSNAME.WHSNNAME
        ,VALID_BIN.BIN_TYPE
        ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITSOURCE
        ,CUSTOMER.CSNAME
        ,ORDERS.ORDER_NO
        ,ORDERS.CUST_PO_NO
        ,ORDERS.QTY_ORDERED
        ,PRODUCT_CODE.DESCR
        ,SALESAGENT.SANAME
        ,ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG
        ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
        ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITCOMMENT
ORDER BY [Date of Inventory]
```

Comment: What does your script do? How is it wrong?

Comment: You already wrote ```ORDER BY [Date of Inventory]```, is that your column name?

Comment: Specifically the MAX doesn't really seem to do anything. I'm still getting lots of entries for the same INVBTICKETNO. Luckily my Where clause keeps the data set pretty small, because otherwise I'd be pulling near three million entries.

Comment: It's the user-facing column name, I guess. yeah.

Comment: ```MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) AS [Trans Date]``` works. You have a column ```INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_LST_ACTIVITY```, doesnt that provide you the information you seek?

Comment: Why are there this many table joined together? You started learning SQL 2 days ago? I suppose your query stems from a tool? Do you really need every single one of those tables?

Comment: INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_LST_ACTIVITY has everything rounding to midnight so if there's multiple transactions on the same ticket in the same day it wouldn't be able to tell which is the newest one, I think.

Comment: I am using dbForge Studio. But I received the bulk of the code from my company's database/network admin who builds these reports in a different piece of software. I'm trying to reverse engineer it for my own purposes.

Comment: The ```GROUP BY``` groups by every column provided. Your Ticket are output in every row containing something that can not be grouped because of different values. Check why you retrieve the same Ticket No.

Answer (score 1):

I found https://kristiannielsen.livejournal.com/6745.html and implemented their "fastest" solution.

Except it doesn't seem very fast... 1 min 12 seconds for 217 rows returned. Do queries run slower if you're working remotely?

```
SELECT
  WHSNAME.WHSNNAME AS [Warehouse Name]
 ,VALID_BIN.BIN_TYPE AS T
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBBINNO AS [Bin Number]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBITEMNO AS [Item Number]
 ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.DESCR AS [Item Description]
 ,PRODUCT_CODE.DESCR AS [Product Code & Description]
 ,CUSTOMER.CSNAME AS [Customer Name]
 ,ORDERS.ORDER_NO AS [Order Number]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_OF_INVENTORY AS [Date of Inventory]
 ,tra1.ITTICKETNO AS [Ticket Number]
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBQTYONHAND AS [Qty on Hand]
 ,ORDERS.QTY_ORDERED AS [Qty Ordered]
 ,INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.SQUARE_FEET_UNIT AS MSF
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.EXTENDED_CST AS [Valuation?]
 ,tra1.ITSOURCE AS Source
 ,tra1.ITCOMMENT AS Comment
 ,tra1.ITTRANDATE AS [Trans Date]
 ,ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG AS Flag
 ,SALESAGENT.SANAME AS [Sales Agent]
 ,ORDERS.CUST_PO_NO AS [Customer PO Number]
FROM dbo.INVENTORY_TRAN tra1
**INNER JOIN (SELECT
    INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO
   ,MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) AS ITTRANDATE
  FROM dbo.INVENTORY_TRAN
  GROUP BY INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO) tra2
  ON tra1.ITTICKETNO = tra2.ITTICKETNO
    AND tra1.ITTRANDATE = tra2.ITTRANDATE**
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_BIN
  ON tra1.ITTICKETNO = INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBITEMNO = INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.ITEM_NO
INNER JOIN dbo.PRODUCT_CODE
  ON INVENTORY_ITEM_TAB.PROD_CD = PRODUCT_CODE.PROD_CD
INNER JOIN dbo.ORDERS
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.ORDER_NO = ORDERS.ORDER_NO
INNER JOIN dbo.WHSNAME
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBWHSNCODE = WHSNAME.WHSNCODE
INNER JOIN dbo.CUSTOMER
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.CSCODE = CUSTOMER.CSCODE
INNER JOIN dbo.SALESAGENT
  ON CUSTOMER.SACODE = SALESAGENT.SACODE
INNER JOIN dbo.VALID_BIN
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBWHSNCODE = VALID_BIN.WHSNCODE
    AND VALID_BIN.BIN_ID = INVENTORY_BIN.INVBBINNO
WHERE ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG = 'R'
ORDER BY [Date of Inventory]
```

Comment: Glad you could solve it! Performance issues are another topic. Which dbms is this? MS SQL Server / T-SQL by any chance?

Comment: (https://blog.devart.com/sql-server-execution-plans.html) maybe a bit advanced, but if you have performance issues you can check out the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

I rebuilt the query from scratch and it seems to work, though I don't have nearly all the columns added back in yet.

```
SELECT
  MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) AS expr1
 ,INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
 ,ORDERS.ORDER_NO
 ,ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG
FROM dbo.INVENTORY_TRAN
INNER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_BIN
  ON INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO = INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
INNER JOIN dbo.ORDERS
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.ORDER_NO = ORDERS.ORDER_NO
WHERE ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG = 'r'
GROUP BY INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
        ,ORDERS.ORDER_NO
        ,ORDERS.FOR_INVT_FLG
ORDER BY INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO
```

Comment: Yes! Keep going, eventually one column will give you a ticket twice.

Comment: These two seem to be the culprit. 

INVENTORY_TRAN.ITSOURCE AS Source
 ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITCOMMENT AS Comment

Comment: Which means a Ticket has multiple comments and mulitple sources. Do you need those in your query?

Comment: My boss uses the comment field to see what type of transaction is was. Automatic adjustment, manual adjustment, etc. So I would at least need that one in there.

Comment: And what do you want to do with that? Keep it and display every comment by outputting it next to related ```MAX(ITTRANDATE)```? You are retrieving every distinct comment.

Comment: I only need the newest entry for each ticket because if the system is working properly the material tied to the ticket would only exist where the most recent entry says it exists. So I only need the rows with the highest ITTRANDATE per each unique INVBTICKETNO.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.INVENTORY_TRAN INVENTORY_TRAN
  ON INVENTORY_BIN.INVBTICKETNO = INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO
    AND INVENTORY_BIN.DATE_LST_ACTIVITY < INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE
```

then add the columns in a sub select, which determines the comment-row with the most recent date:

```
INNER JOIN (SELECT
   INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO
   ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITSOURCE AS [Source]
   ,INVENTORY_TRAN.ITCOMMENT AS [Comment]
   ,MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) [Trans Date]
FROM [INVENTORY_TRAN]
GROUP BY INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTICKETNO, INVENTORY_TRAN.ITSOURCE, INVENTORY_TRAN.ITCOMMENT
HAVING MAX(INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE) = INVENTORY_TRAN.ITTRANDATE
) AS [sub_INVENTORY_TRAN] ON [INVENTORY_BIN].[INVBTICKETNO] = [sub_INVENTORY_TRAN].[ITTICKETNO]
```

You also need to replace the selected columns with the new added through the sub select:

```
   ,[sub_INVENTORY_TRAN].[Source]
   ,[sub_INVENTORY_TRAN].[Comment]
   ,[sub_INVENTORY_TRAN].[Trans Date]
```

Comment: Kinda hard to do this blindly. Hope you understand what i mean. Reduce [INVENTORY_TRAN] to only rows with most recent [ITTRANDATE]

Comment: Oh, nope, not quite. That should produce about the same output.

Comment: Thank you for your help TheDudeWithHat. Apologies, but I couldn't make heads or tails of your solution so I kept poking around for solutions that I could work from as a starting point.